# Block entire network instead of individual hosts on it

Tags: windows, unix

Using `C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` or `/etc/hosts` file, it is possible to block individual hosts, by sending them to `127.0.0.1` or to non-existent IP address. Example:

```
192.68.0.254 abc.def.domain.suffix
```

What if I want to block all hosts under `def.domain.suffix`, including itself? Is it possible to use some other similar network configuration files to block them?

Comment: “What if I want to block all hosts under def.domain.suffix, including itself?” - Use a software or hardware firewall

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you want within the hosts file.

The way to accomplish this is to send queries through a nameserver you control, and that provides the answers you want for the domain and its subdomains.  How you do this would depend on the nameserver, but if you are at the place where you can run a combined recursive and authorative nameserver, its fairly easy and can be done multiple ways.   (I know both Bind and DNSMasq can do this - the latter is commonly found on better SOHO routers and many Linux systems)